# How to validate a raw Zebra Programming Language (ZPL) file with a regular expression?

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

When receiving ZPL raw labels (text files) from a third party, I would like to run a regular expression on them to validate them.

Rather than a 100% strict validation, I am mostly looking to avoid sending to the printer obviously wrong files, such as completely unrelated text files, or binary files.

I am not familiar enough with ZPL/ZPL-II and I would prefer to use an existing resource for that. Would you know if one exists?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of one. But it wouldn't be too hard to validate. ZPL is pretty straightforward, especially if there's a very defined set that you send to your printer...

The ZPL command characters are `~` for immediate commands an `^` for formatting commands.

Label formats must begin with a `^XA` and end with a `^XZ`.

Download commands typically begin with a `~D<something>`, like `~DY`, `~DG`, `~DT`, `~DC` etc.

There are a couple status commands like `~HI` and `~HS`

There may be a couple other edge cases, but these are the most common commands.

Comment: Wait a minute. The specs for ZPL are available https://files.tracerplus.com/public/docs/3rdparty/manuals/ZPL_Vol1.pdf, https://files.tracerplus.com/public/docs/3rdparty/manuals/ZPL_Vol2.pdf. Whilst ZPL may be simpler that C# and more structured than English would you try to write a compiler or NLP with a regular expression?